# Laravel - return response from helper

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a public API using Laravel 5.2. To keep the code in the controller short, I have created several helper functions, one of which is a function to return a response to the API call, as shown below:

```
if (! function_exists('buildResponse'))
{
    function buildResponse($data)
    {
        return response()->json($data)->header('foo', 'bar');
    }
}
```

This is how I would call it from the controller:

```
public function registration()
{
    buildResponse(['a' => 'Success']);
}
```

However this does not work. It only works if I add a `return` in front of the function.

```
public function registration()
{
    return buildResponse(['a' => 'Success']);
}
```

One might say, "Okay, then just include the `return`!". The thing is, this particular function will be called by another helper function, for example:

```
if (! function_exists('throwResponseCode'))
{
    /**
     * Throws a response code to the client.
     * @param $code
     * @return mixed
     */
    function throwResponseCode($code)
    {
        switch ($code) {
            case '101':
                $data[$code] = 'Unable to establish a database connection';
                return buildResponse($data);
            // Other cases here
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can send a response to the client from the helper function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keep it **simple** bro! 
**Change**

```
 return response()->json($data)->header('foo', 'bar');
```

**To**

```
 return response()->json($data)->header('foo', 'bar')->send();
```

Comment: It _almost_ works! I just need the controller to finish its execution after the response has been sent. Adding a `die()` doesn't finish it, nor do I think it's an elegant way of finishing.

Comment: Yes. You should don't do anything after sending response to the browser

Comment: that is extremely helpful, why I didn't see this anywere before?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. Not directly.

The purpose of `return` is to finish the function and give results. Laravel considers  the return value of controller to be the response, so other functions can not do this using return.

There are someways around this. Consider this. Create a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware), that works after the response has been generated by controller, i.e. calls `$next($request)` in the first line. Here you can change the response as you wish. To connect helpers to this middleware, you can use static methods or properties. The logic of middleware would be that if someone has put something in, say, `$response` static property of middleware, then send this one instead of controller response.